# Writing a python dictionary from a text file with an unusual format

Tags: python

I am trying to creat a python dictionary from a text file that is formatted in this way. I cannot change it.

```
dataname
definition of data
dataname2
definition of data2
dataname3
definition of data3
```

The data is routinely unspaced. The keys have to be the the dataname and the values have to be the definition of the data. I know I need readlines() or to keep track of which line is a key and which is a value somehow. This is what I have. Any help is appreciated.

```
d = {}
with open('dict.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    for line in myFile:
        x = myFile.readlines()
        word = x[0]
        description = x[1]
        d[word] = description
    print(d)
```

Comment: Do you mean 1st line will be `Key` and second line will be `value` always ?

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on the file with a `for` loop, which will iterate on the lines, and use the `next` method of the file object to iterate to the next line:

```
d = {}

with open('dict.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name = line.strip()
        description = next(f).strip()
        d[name] = description

print(d)
#{'dataname': 'definition of data', 'dataname2': 'definition of data2', 'dataname3': 'definition of data3'}
```

Comment: This might throw an error if the number of lines in the file is `odd` ??

Comment: We should have a check for that I think. Processing everything and getting error is not likable. Just a thought. :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from itertools to do:

```
import itertools
ur_dict={}
with open(ur_file) as f:
    for line1,line2 in itertools.zip_longest(*[f]*2):
        ur_dict[line1.rstrip()]=line2.rstrip()

>>> ur_dict
{'dataname': 'definition of data', 'dataname2': 'definition of data2', 'dataname3': 'definition of data3'}
```

Which could be a dict comprehension:

```
with open('so.txt') as f:
    ur_dict={line1.rstrip():line2.rstrip() 
            for line1,line2 in itertools.zip_longest(*[f]*2)}
```

Or, you can use `zip` with the iterator twice:

```
with open(ur_file) as f:
    ur_dict={l1.rstrip():l2.rstrip() for l1,l2 in zip(f,f)}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Code:

```
d = {}
file = open('dict.txt', 'r')
text = file.read().strip()
file.close()

textlist = text.split('\n')
for i in range(0, len(textlist), 2):
    colname = textlist[i]
    colvalue = [textlist[i+1]]
    d[colname] = colvalue
#display dictionary
print(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
#display dataframe 
print(df)
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('dict.txt', 'r') as file:
    split = file.read().splitlines()
    dictionary = {k:v for k, v in zip(split[::2], split[1::2])}
```

```
{'dataname': 'definition of data',
 'dataname2': 'definition of data2',
 'dataname3': 'definition of data3'}
```

---

```
print(file.splitlines()[::2]) 
# >>> ['dataname', 'dataname2', 'dataname3']

print(file.splitlines()[1::2])
# >>> ['definition of data', 'definition of data2', 'definition of data3']
```

Use `slice(start, stop, step)` operation to give you odd and even list items.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like below.

1. Read all the lines into a list with each line being a separate element in list.
2. Create a sub_list out of main list to be considered as `keys`. This would be alternate elements from main list starting from `element 0`.
3. Create a sub_list out of main list to be considered as `values`. This would be alternate elements from main list starting from `element 1`.
4. Merge the 2 lists so that 1st element from key_list is mapped with 1st element of value_list.

Try this :

```
with open('dict.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content]   # to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line

key_list = content[::2]       # every alternate element in list is treated as keys. Starting from 1st element.
value_list = content[1::2]    # every alternate element in list is treated as value. Starting from 2nd element.

final_dict = dict(zip(key_list, value_list))    # merge the 2 lists to create a key, value pair dictionary.

print(final_dict)
```

Comment: how would strip the trailing white space ?

Comment: Did not understand what you are asking. But if you want to remove trailing spaces from a string, use `.strip()` as done in above code.